# Is storing CVV/CVC phone PCI compliant?

Tags: payment, credit-card, pci-compliance

We would like to store user CC information including CVV/CVC for some application logic.

Is that PCI compliant if we

1. Store CC number on server
2. Store CVC/CVV on mobile phone
3. When user approves send CVV to server & perform payment there. CVV is never stored on server.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Store CC number on server

Only if you encrypt it and follow PCI guidelines for securing that data (i.e. physical and logical access to the server)

> Store CVC/CVV on mobile phone. When user approves send CVV to server & perform payment there. CVV is never stored on server.

No. You cannot store this information, ever.

Comment: Good advice, but not quite true John. The CVV can be stored *pre-authorisation only*, which I think is what the questioner is asking here. Once auth has been performed the CVV must be deleted, and (as you say) cannot be stored **post** authorisation anywhere.

Comment: @PaulG You're right. I could have made myself clearer.